# Conditional distribution

Tags: conditional-probability

For my stats summer work, we were givin data to evaluate and perform problems with. They were the grades of a stats test between two class. A first period and last period class. I've gotten up to the conditional probability section. I've looked it up but I am not sure if I am doing it right. One example is the conditional of the first period class that got an A on the test. The data given is that one person in the first class got an A and 3 people got an A in the last class. There are 21 students in the first and 30 in the last, making the total 51. Now I tried, and did them all. For the A's, I got 2/51 for the first class and 2/17 for the last class. I did this for all the grades and added up the fractions to 2. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very unclear - what conditional probability are you after?

Also, if **all** the probabilities ever add up to anything other than 1 then you are, beyond a shadow of a doubt, wrong. If any of the probabilities are negative or greater than one you are wrong. If any subset of the non-zero probabilities is greater than 1 then you are wrong.

To demonstrate, define the events:

$$F\text{ - student is in the first class}$$
$$L\text{ - student is in the last class}$$
$$A\text{ - student got an A}$$

From the data stated:

$$P(F) = \frac{21}{51}$$
$$P(L) = \frac{30}{51}$$
$$P(A) = \frac{4}{51}$$
$$P(A|F) = \frac{1}{21}$$
$$P(A|L) = \frac{3}{30}$$

A *typical* question would be "Given that this student got an A, what is the probability that they are in the first class"

$$\begin{align}
P(F|A)&=\frac{P(A|F)P(F)}{P(A)}\\
&=\frac{\frac{1}{21}\frac{21}{51}}{\frac{4}{51}}\\
&=\frac{1}{4}\\
\end{align}$$